# How to modify array in_place for the merge sort algorithm?[edited]

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

I was trying to write the merge function for the merge sort here.

While I'm trying to write the function recursively, I can't figure it out a way to modify the variable `nums1` globally.

I can't pass test4 as the modified `nums1` is never returned globally.

```
class Solution(object):
    def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n):
        if not nums1:
            nums1[:] = nums2
            return

        if not nums2:
            return

        if nums1[0] < nums2[0]:
            self.merge(nums1[1: ], m - 1, nums2, n)
            return

        if nums1[0] >= nums2[0]:
            nums1[0], nums1[1:] = nums2[0], nums1[:]
            self.merge(nums1, m + 1, nums2[1:], n - 1)
            return



if __name__ == "__main__":
    # nums1 = [1, 2, 3]
    # nums2 = [-1, 4, 5]
    # Solution().merge(nums1, 3, nums2, 3)
    # assert nums1 == [-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    nums1 = []
    nums2 = [2, 3, 4]
    Solution().merge(nums1, 0, nums2, 3)
    print("Outside", nums1)
    assert nums1 == [2, 3, 4]
    print('Test 1 passed!')

    nums1 = [1, 2, 3]
    nums2 = []
    Solution().merge(nums1, 3, nums2, 0)
    assert nums1 == [1, 2, 3]
    print('Test 2 passed!')

    nums1 = [1, 2, 3]
    nums2 = [-1]
    Solution().merge(nums1, 3, nums2, 1)
    assert nums1 == [-1, 1, 2, 3]
    print("Test 3 passed!")

    nums1 = [1, 2, 3]
    nums2 = [1.5]
    Solution().merge(nums1, 3, nums2, 1)
    print('outside nums1: ', nums1)
    assert nums1 == [1, 1.5, 2, 3]
    print("Test 4 passed!")
```

Comment: I don't see a `num1` variable in your code; did you mean `nums1`?

Comment: Yes that's what I meant

Answer (score 0):

If a sub range of a list is used in an expression (here especially as parameter of a function call) and not as left side of an assignment, a new independent list is created:

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3]
>>> numsSub = nums[1:]
>>> numsSub[0] = 7
>>> nums
[1, 2, 3]
>>> numsSub
[7, 3]
```

Possible solutions:

1. Assign the sublist before the call to a separate variable, use it in the call as parameter and copy it back into `nums1` after the call
2. Add a parameter to `merge` which tells the first item of `nums1` which should be processed and give always the full `nums1` as parameter, something like:

`def merge(self, nums1, m, nums2, n, base=0):
    ...
            self.merge(nums1, m - 1, nums2, n, base + 1)`

Comment: could you elaborate more how this would affect my code please?

Comment: @jen007 If you recursively call `self.merge(nums1[1: ], m - 1, nums2, n)` then the `nums1[1: ]` is a list of its own which is lost immediately after the call without modification of `nums1`

Comment: Is there a way of retaining ```nums1``` in the recursive call?

Comment: I have added 2 possible solutions